# [Laravel][Routing] How to pass param to controller respective with route parameter

Tags: laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I met a problem, although i searched many places but could not find the answer. So, i ask here for a support.
I want to pass param into controller function that respective with param in route.
Please see below example:
I want these routes to **Check** controller , function **getByTime($time)**

```
Route::get('/hourly', 'Check@getByTime');
Route::get('/daily', 'Check@getByTime');
Route::get('/weekly', 'Check@getByTime');

class Check {
    function getByTime($time) {}
}
```

Example conditions:

```
hourly: $time=1
daily: $time=24
weekly: $time = 24*7
```

I mean like this:

```
Route::get('/hourly', 'Check@getByTime(1)');
Route::get('/daily', 'Check@getByTime(24)');
Route::get('/weekly', 'Check@getByTime(168)');
```

Please help me to resolve it. 
Sorry for my bad explanation, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I have understood your exact problem, but this will do a trick

```
Route::get('{slug}', function ($slug){
   if ($slug == "hourly") {
       App::call('App\Http\Controllers\Check@getByTime', [1]);
   } else if ($slug == "daily") {
       App::call('App\Http\Controllers\Check@getByTime', [24]);
   } else if ($slug == "weekly") {
       App::call('App\Http\Controllers\Check@getByTime', [168]);
   }
});
```

But you have add this at top of all routes.

Comment: That's amazing. I did it. This is what i need. Many thank to you, bro.

Comment: @TinhNV Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This is so simple,If you check laravel document you will find solution easily.here is the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#required-parameters).

By the way you can do it simply like below

```
Route::get('/hourly/{hour}', 'Check@getByTime');
Route::get('/daily/{day}', 'Check@getByTime');
Route::get('/weekly/{week}', 'Check@getByTime');
```

```
class Check {
    function getByTime($time) {}
}
```

and pass parameter in url like

```
http://yourhost/hourly/1
http://yourhost/daily/24
http://yourhost/weekly/168
```

As per your requirement you could try this:

```
Route::get('/hourly', 'Check@getByTime')->defaults('hour', 1);
```

Comment: Hi, may be my bad explanation make you mis-understand my mean.
I mean if you access `http://myhost/hourly`, `getByTime($time)` will get `$time=1` automatically.

Comment: Ah!, Then you can use `Route::currentRouteName();` in your controller to get current route and then can handle it conditionally, like `Route::get('/hourly', 'Check@getByTime')->name('hour');`  some thing like that.

Comment: Sorry, sure i can do it in controller by manual. but i need it is passed and generated automatically. I mean, if you request `/hourly`, your `$time` must be 1; if you request `/daily`, your `$time` must be 24.... Or some thing like this.
Example:
function getByTime($time) {
    echo $time * 2;
}
I don't want to change code in my function, but i also need to:
- Request to `http://myhost/hourly` ==> return 2
- Request to `http://myhost/daily` ==> return 48

Comment: pls check my updated answer with `->defaults('hour', 1);`